# How are eigenvectors and principal components related?

Tags: pca

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making sense of principal component analysis, eigenvectors & eigenvalues](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues)

I am currently going through a PCA tutorial. However, I am a bit confused. For PCA, we calculate the covariance matrix and then find the eigen vectors and eigen values of the covariance matrix. These vectors are the principal components.

- How are the eigenvectors and the principal components related?
- Why does finding the covariance matrix from the data and its eigenvectors are the principal components?